# R Studio Commands

Tags: r

To filter out species that appear fewer than 50 times in your database (filter our rare species) you would first make a list of species and count them, then you would type in what command?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need ti understand the structure of your data and clear information about your expected output. A reproducible sample would help us on that. Refer this to know how to get a reproducible sample. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example